# Why is AS3 creating new instances in for loop?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, movieclip

Strangest behavior I have seen from actionscript so far and I have been working with AS for over 10 years.

```
var clip1:MovieCip = new MovieClip();  
var clip2:MovieCip = new MovieClip();  
var clip3:MovieCip = new MovieClip();    
var clip;

var myarray:Array = new Array(clip1, clip2, clip3);    

for each (clip in myarray)
{ removeChild(clip);
  clip = new mc();
  trace(clip.name); }
```

seems simple enough right? well for some reason flash is changing the instance names to instanceX where X is some randomly assigned number and I am no longer able to call on the clips by their assigned names, for example if I try...

```
 clip1.x = 300;
```

flash will not throw an error but clip1.x does not move to 300. I have been working on this for a few hours, it seems the movieclips actually still exist but flash has created new movieclips! Please help

Comment: The title does not seem to match the question. It's creating new instances because you are calling `new mc();` in the loop but I guess that is not what you mean. Can you explain what you are trying to do in the code? You seem to be removing MCs from the stage in the loop but later try to set their position. You are also not storing the new MC instances anywhere.

Comment: I am removing the clips from stages, changing the clip for the instances to a different movieclip and then readding them. new MovieClip() means its a blank movieclip, I am giving them the mc movielcip, let's assume it is not blank. Flash wont let me call "clip = mc()" you have to put NEW in front of it

Comment: the point is that this all works if you call each instance individually not using an array, if you use an array like so, it creates new instances, probably because adobe is garbage and cant get their code straight

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you don't understand the difference between member names and instance names. I assume that you write code on the timeline, that means you operate inside the **MovieClip** object that is represented by that timeline (might be the main timeline, in this case you are operating inside the **root**).

**Member** is an OOP word that represents **fields** (plain data and object references) and **methods** (bound functions) of the object. You can use dot notation or square bracket notation to access the members:

```
this['a'] = 10;
trace(this.a); // output: 10
```

When you are writing code on timeline, when you declare variables or functions, you are actually declaring fields and methods (respectively) of the current **MovieClip**:

```
var a:int = 10;

trace(a);         // output: 10
trace(this.a);    // output: 10
trace(this['a']); // output: 10
```

Keep in mind that variables, declared inside function bodies, are not object members but the local function variables:

```
function A():void
{
    var a:int = 999;

    trace(a);      // output: 999
    trace(this.a); // output: undefined
}
```

Instance names are class members of **DisplayObject** class under a "name" name.

```
trace(name);         // output: instance123
trace(this.name);    // output: instance123
trace(this['name']); // output: instance123
```

The confusing part about it is that Flash auto-declares pre-designed things as the object members with the member names same as instance names. So, if you put some **MovieClip** with the instance name **MC1**, you can address it as following:

```
trace(MC1);         // output: [object MovieCip]
trace(this.MC1);    // output: [object MovieCip]
trace(this['MC1']); // output: [object MovieCip]
trace(getChildByName("MC1"));      // output: [object MovieCip]
trace(this.getChildByName("MC1")); // output: [object MovieCip]
```

You can turn the auto-declare option off at **File > Publish Settings > AS3 Setings > Auto-declare Stage Instances**. If you do so, the output will be different:

```
trace(MC1);         // output: undefined
trace(this.MC1);    // output: undefined
trace(this['MC1']); // output: undefined
trace(getChildByName("MC1"));      // output: [object MovieCip]
trace(this.getChildByName("MC1")); // output: [object MovieCip]
```

Also, that auto-declare thing works, let me stress it again, only with pre-designed content. If you create new instances of anything and **addChild(...)** them to the container, it won't automatically add their references as the container OOP members.

Then, how it affects your problem.

You call **clip1.x = 300;** and there's no error. Of course there are none. The **clip1** member still holds the reference to the originally declared and instantiated **var clip1:MovieCip = new MovieClip();** and you never reassigned anything to this member. So you address the valid **MovieClip** that is not attached to anything, but that does not matter to AS3 or Flash platform: you are performing a valid operation on valid object.

If you want to address the newly created instances, you should do it via the array you put them to, or via carefully organized instance names, or by assigning their references to the members of respective member names:

```
var clip0:MovieCip = new MovieClip;
var clip1:MovieCip = new MovieClip;
var clip2:MovieCip = new MovieClip;
var clip3:MovieCip = new MovieClip;

var myarray:Array = new Array(clip0, clip1, clip2, clip3);

for (var i:int = 0; i < myarray.length; i++)
{
    // You better call the class MC, because lowercase
    // class name looks like a variable name.
    var aClip:MC = new MC;

    // Give it a proper instance name.
    aClip.name = "clip" + i;

    // Assign it as a member of current object.
    this["clip" + i] = aClip;

    // Put it to designated place into the Array.
    myarray[i] = aClip;
}
```

Now you can address it any way you want:

```
trace(clip1);         // output: [object MC]
trace(this.clip1);    // output: [object MC]
trace(this['clip1']); // output: [object MC]
trace(myarray[1]);    // output: [object MC]
trace(getChildByName("clip1"));      // output: [object MC]
trace(this.getChildByName("clip1")); // output: [object MC]
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly you want to replace the three MovieClips that are referenced by variables in a loop. The issue here is that assigning a new MovieClip instance to the `clip` variable does not change or overwrite the old MovieClip that it referenced. The old empty MovieClips still exist (even though they are removed from the stage) and are still assigned to the variables `clip1`, `clip2` and `clip3`.

You can update these variable like this:

```
for each (clip in myarray) {
    removeChild(clip); 
    var newClip:MovieClip = new mc(); // create new MC
    this["clip" + i] = newClip; // set variables (e.g. clip1, clip2, ...)
}
```

In case you also want to update the array, you probably want to do something like this:

```
for (var i:uint = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
    var clip:MovieClip = myarray[i];
    removeChild(clip); 
    var newClip:MovieClip = new mc(); // create new MC
    myarray[i] = newClip; // overwrite the old clip in the array
    this["clip" + i] = newClip; // set variables (e.g. clip1, clip2, ...)
}
```