# How do I access more objects in AS3 without writing a line for each of them?

Tags: actionscript-3

Let's say I've got 5 objects in flash and I want to change a few of their properties; Their names are thing1, thing2, and so on. When I've got 3 or 4 MovieClips it's easy because I'll just write a line for each of them, but sometimes it comes to a few hundreds objects.

```
thing1.alpha = 0.5;
thing2.alpha = 0.5;
thing3.alpha = 0.5;
thing4.alpha = 0.5;
```

And instead of this, I want something like this:

```
var nr: int;
for (nr = 1; nr <= 4; nr++){
    MovieClip(String("thing" + String(nr))).alpha = 0.5;
}
```

I know that will not work, but is there any way I can replace that "String" with something that will do?

(I don't want to do this adding Childs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Array**s and loops is the answer.

You can list all the objects first and access them via **Array**:

```
var aList:Array = [thing1, thing2, thing3, thing4];
var aThing:DisplayObject;

for each (aThing in aList)
{
    aThing.alpha = 0.5;
}
```

You can access objects in the container if you know how to construct their names:

```
for (var i:int = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
    var aName:String = "thing" + i;
    var aThing:DisplayObject = getChildByName(aName);

    aThing.alpha = 0.5;
}
```

**UDP:** Usually I don't encourage this because of certain implications (and I still think that sticking to listing ahead or the use of **getChildByName(...)** are more reliable approaches in that very order), but well, whatever. You can also address nested objects via square bracket notation, but this works only on:

- initially designed objects with **File > Publish Settings > AS3 Settings > Auto-declare Stage Instances** set to **ON** (it is **ON** by default, yet it's good to know this anyway);
- objects added in run-time which you explicitly assigned as the members of the given container with the same names as the objects' own instance names.

Also, I really advise to read up my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51306321/4687633), it highlights the addressing topic in details.

```
for (var i:int = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
    var aName:String = "thing" + i;
    var aThing:MovieClip = this[aName];

    aThing.alpha = 0.5;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, my IQ just increased today with about 0.1 thanks to you :D I was wondering what kind of variables would work like objects, because until now I kinda avoided to work with the displayobject container

Comment: @AlexNegru Ok, I've updated my answer and hope you will find the additional read quite enlightening.

Comment: Neat, I never knew there was an actual option for "Auto-declare Stage Instances". All this time, I thought flash just worked like that.

Comment: @mitim I think it was the only available behavior back then in AS1/2 days, so they made it a default option to prevent people from frustrating while moving to AS3.

Comment: I've already finished my application using getChildByName(). It is one damn useful function, and it made my work easier in many other cases. Thank you :D