# Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties. (MovieClip Error)

Tags: actionscript-3

AS3 newbie here (like really new). I'm trying to make a puzzle game with actionscript, and below is the code: (put in an as file applied to fla)

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        var xPos:int;
        var yPos:int;

        public function Main():void
        {
            addListeners(pr1c1, pr1c2, pr1c3, pr1c4, pr2c1, pr2c2, pr2c3, pr2c4, pr3c1, pr3c2, pr3c3, pr3c4);
        }

        private function getPosition(target:Object):void
        {
            xPos = target.x;
            yPos = target.y;
        }

        private function dragObject(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            getPosition(e.target);

            e.target.startDrag(true);
        }

        private function stopDragObject(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if (e.target.hitTestObject(getChildByName("p" + e.target.name)))
            {
                e.target.x = getChildByName("p" + e.target.name).x;
                e.target.y = getChildByName("p" + e.target.name).y;
            }
            else
            {
                e.target.x = xPos;
                e.target.y = yPos;
            }

            e.target.stopDrag();
        }
    
        private function addListeners(...objects):void
        {
            for (var i:int = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
            {
                objects[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragObject);
                objects[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragObject);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(pr1c1, pr1c2...) are the puzzle pieces, instances of movie clips that are supposed to snap to position when they are dragged to the correct positions.

the code returns with:
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
at Main/addListeners()
at Main()

i've already checked the instances and they are all correctly named.

Comment: In the **Main** constructor put **trace(pr1c1, pr1c2, pr1c3, pr1c4, pr2c1, pr2c2, pr2c3, pr2c4, pr3c1, pr3c2, pr3c3, pr3c4);** If they don't trace correctly, that means they are not initialized at the moment, even if they are "*correctly named*". Also, you might want to read this one answer that clarifies certain things between display object names and parent display container properties: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51306321/4687633

Comment: @Organis Thank you so much! I believe the problem is fixed now -- the main problem was probably that I forgot to add the proper linkages to the pngs of the symbols. The trace code helped massively. :)